# Why Does DateTimeConverter.ConvertFrom Work with Empty Strings?

Tags: c#, .net

When doing DateTimeConverter.ConvertFromString(" ") it gives back a DateTime.MinValue. You can have as many blank spaces as you want and it still works. If you give it an empty string, it will return null, which I would expect.

This behavior is different than all the other TypeConverters that will either return null or throw an exception.

This is also different than the behavior of DateTime.TryParse(" ") which returns false meaning it didn't work.

I would expect the ConvertFrom method to behave the same as the TryParse method where it should fail if there is an empty or whitespace string.

Why does it do this? Is this a bug?

I'm doing some type conversion and this is a situation where I'm getting unexpected/inconsistent behavior. Is there a way to reliably do type conversion that works for all types? Or do I need to put a special clause in for the DateTime case?

```
if( typeConverter is DateTimeConverter )
{
    // Check if the value is a white space string.
}
```

Comment: Checked the decompiled IL and it specifically checks for an empty string and returns the null value.  Sorry, but I don't think anybody can answer this but a few people on the WPF team at MS.  Also, there are two versions of this, one of which offloads the work to the DateTimeValueSerializer.  The ConvertFromString method specifies that an empty string returns the minimum value.  I guess the biggest concern here is to prevent exceptions being thrown in the design surface, but that's a WAG.

Comment: @Will it's fair to say no one can conjecture about *why* it has this behavior, but, having looked at the decompiled method, can you confirm it handles *whitespace* explicitly? That's what the OP was asking about, as its handling differs from the behavior of `DateTime.Parse`, which DateTimeConverter.ConvertFrom [apparently uses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.datetimeconverter.aspx).

Comment: @djacobson: "Why does it do this? Is this a bug?"  The answer to the second is "No", which isn't exactly an answer (yes/no questions are discouraged here).  The answer to the first one is subjective unless you are a member of the WPF team, as I specified.

Comment: @Will Sorry, I wasn't trying to question the moderation decision. I was just curious, since you've already looked at the method IL, if it does handle the whitespace behavior described by the OP explicitly.

Comment: I would argue that a lot of people from the teams at MS actually answer questions on here quite often, and have a lot higher rep than I do. I guess my ultimate question then is, what should I do? Just handle it as a one off case? Or is there a better way to do type conversion that is consistent? Which are the very last questions in there. Right now I'm going to handle it as a one off case, but I'd like to know if there is a better way. There are a lot of people out there that have more experience with this stuff than I.